# How to keep track of the root object from a class chain in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, chain

```
class Header
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        global $app;
        print($app->config);
    }
}

class Modules
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->header = new Header();
    }
}

class Project
{
    public $config = "config";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->modules = new Modules();
    }
}

$app = new Project();
```

Right now, If I want to access the root object (instance of Project class, that is) from within the `Header` scope, I have to remember the name I picked for the instance (which could vary) and reference to it by using the `global` keyword. But I feel like this is just a quick fix. I need a reliable method of accessing the root object from which the current one (along with its parents) was constructed.

In other words, I will need to access `$app` inside `$app->modules->header` giving the fact that the name `app` itself is variable and the length of the chain is also dynamic.

I can access the parent's namespace `parent::` but it would've been nice to have something like `first_ancestor::`.

Comment: You can use `get_parent_class()` in a loop to dig back up the inheritance tree.

Comment: @MarcB: there's no inheritance here.

Comment: In general, what you want to do is a horrible idea. "modules" (eg: objects) shouldn't know about their surrounding environment. That would just kill the whole idea of black box abstraction.

Comment: @MarcB I believe that that only works when you have classes that `extend` each other.

Comment: use a global `$app`, or if you have more of these, a global configuration object, or, if you hate singletons, pass the `$app` in the constructor to each relevant objects so they know who their "ancestor" is.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Alright, but what if I want to make use of some general app configuration inside the header module? Maybe I'll want to know the encoding of the page so I can echo it, considering that the encoding config is saved in `$app->config`. Does this kill anything?

Comment: I already told you the options, and all of them will solve the problem. What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, that was a reply to your second comment, before you listed the options. Thank you, I'll try to use a global config object.

Comment: Ah ok... just make sure that your system remains flexible enough (e.g.: don't end up with a god object). for large systems, avoid globals...

Comment: did you know, that you can pass values in the constructor?

Comment: @tereško I want to keep my application's logic solid and straight to the point. I don't want bounce around the `$root` and pass it through every constructor I have, that would feel weird and not reliable.

Comment: @AndreiPham I hope you realize the irony of that statement. By not passing the value in the constructor, you are explicitly bouncing around, locating globals, making your application's logic tangled (not sound, and not straight to the point). It would not be reliable at all either. What he's saying is actually the correct answer to your problem.

Comment: @DanLugg No, I'm not trolling. If you read my question properly, you would have known by now that I did not use nor did I intend to use `global` at all. I used it to illustrate what my problem is. Moreover, I did not say that `first_ancestor::` exists. All I have done was to express my need for an alternative for such a feature.

Comment: @AndreiPham That's all fine and well. Go with ircmaxell's answer; specifically the "**Even Better Yet**"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, in the spirit of answering the question, of course there's a way (warning: *here be dragons*):

```
function YouAreAnIdiotIfYouDoThisForReal($skip = 0) {
    $bt = debug_backtrace();
    if (isset($bt[1]['function']) && $bt[1]['function'] === "__construct") {
        // called from constructor, so skip it!
        $skip++;
    }
    foreach ($bt as $stack) {
        if (isset($stack['function']) && $stack['function'] === "__construct" && $skip-- <= 0) {
            return $stack['object'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which can be used as so:

```
class Header
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->project = YouAreAnIdiotIfYouDoThisForReal(1);
        $this->modules = YouAreAnIdiotIfYouDoThisForReal();
    }
}
```

Now, this does what you ask. But please, under **NO CIRCUMSTANCES** should you actually do that.

Seriously.

I cannot stress how bad it would be if you were doing that.

It's fragile.

And dirty.

And relies on debug functionality.

And hard-coded relationships between construction order.

And other garbage.

## Real Answer:

Instead, refactor to accept explicit dependencies:

```
class Header
{
    public function __construct(Project $project, Modules $modules)
    {
        $this->project = $project;
        $this->modules = $modules;
    }
}

class Modules
{
    public function __construct(Project $project)
    {
        $this->project = $project;
        $this->header = new Header($project, $this);
    }
}

class Project
{
    public $config = "config";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->modules = new Modules($this);
    }
}
```

Your dependencies are explicit, and everything is clear as to what's happening where.

## Even Better Yet

Even better yet, remove New from the equation entirely:

```
class Header
{
    public function __construct(Project $project)
    {
        $this->project = $project;
    }
}

class Modules
{
    public function __construct(Header $header)
    {
        $this->header = $header;
    }
}

class Project
{
    public $config = "config";

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function setModules(Modules $modules) {
        $this->modules = $modules;
    }
}

$project = new Project();
$headers = new Header($project);
$modules = new Modules($headers);
$project->setModules($modules);
```

Now, your code itself will be completely isolated, and not depend on anything. You can override each dependency as needed (say for testing, when you want to inject a fake project into `Header()`)...

This is called [**Dependency Injection**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKD2-MAkXyQ).

Seriously, don't use the first method. It was more of a joke than anything (to show what the power of PHP is, but good lord, no, that's evil...

Comment: Thank. You. @ircmaxell! This was exactly what I was looking for. I know, I said I don't want to juggle with the project reference throughout my whole code, but I was imagining it in a different way. So, back to the answer, you're telling me that I should use the second alternative (Dependency Injection) and not use the first one (which is not Dependency Injection)? I don't want to contradict, but I find the first one more logical. You just initialize the project and that's it, the modules are all built.

Comment: Why is it such a bad practice to integrate `new` in a constructor that I have to take it out and instead of that, start creating the modules manually (not in any order, I have to create the modules first, only after that the actual container), and after that assigning them to the project? I thought the code in the first example was isolated too. I mean, it doesn't depend on anything, because I alwasy pass the project to all the children. And also, why do you have to pass the Modules object to Header through an argument, when you could use `parent::`? I'm sorry if these are stupid questions.

Comment: Oh, I have just watched your Dependency Injection explanation video. I think I get why the second is better than the first.